# Controller for a PartialView

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am Creating a new partial view in MVC 3 as this functionality is required through out my application.Is it possible to have a separate controller for my partial view only

Comment: YOU CAN but that doesn't mean you SHOULD

Comment: Do you want a new controller or a new action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Create controller (consider to disable non-child action calls if you need to use controller only for partial view):

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public PartialViewResult Bar()
    {
        var model = new BarModel();
        return PartialView("_Bar", model);
    }
}
```

And use it

```
@Html.RenderAction("Bar", "Foo")
```